# Group by columns and sum resulting in scientific number

Tags: python, pandas

I am learning data science , and i need to group two columns and sum another column using pandas ,
but the result of sum showing in scientific number , **how to convert this in to general number** & moreover why this is showing scientific number instead of general number .?Kindly help me through this.

[image: Sample dataset]

[image: result dataframe]

group by code

```
Totalsum = data.groupby(['Month','Mac']).agg({'Qty':['sum','mean']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['sum'] = df['sum'].apply(lambda x: '{:.}'.format(np.round(x,0)))
```

or:

```
df['sum'] = df['sum'].apply(lambda x: '%.3f' % x)
```